# Jquery Swype Function on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery function that enables the wow slider on my page. I have a swype function on Jquery mobile that open and closes menu on click left or right swype. The problem is my slider is getting affected as it cant move properly because of the open or close menu. I want the slider to move freely as it was before opening the menu. Please help me how to handle slider separately.

HTML DIV:

```
div id="wowslider-container1">

    <div class="ws_images">
        <ul>
            <!--RepeatStart-->
            <li>
                <img  src="<!--ImagePath-->" alt="<!--ImageAlt-->" title="<!--ImageTitle-->" id="wows1_<!--Index-->" /></li>
            <!--RepeatEnd-->
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>

        jQuery(window).on("swipeleft", function (event) {
            $(".DinM-navbar-toggle").click();


        });
        jQuery(window).on("swiperight", function (event) {
            $(".DinM-navbar-toggle").click();
        });
</script>
 <script>
    jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider({ effect: "", prev: "", next: "", duration: 20 * 100, delay: 20 * 100, width: 1200, height: 400, autoPlay: false, autoPlayVideo: false, playPause: false, stopOnHover: false, loop: false, bullets: 1, caption: false, captionEffect: "none", controls: false, responsive: 2, fullScreen: false, gestures: GESTUREVALUE, onBeforeStep: 0, images: 0 });
    setTimeout(function () { $(".ws_bullets").css("left", ($(".ws_controls").width() - $(".ws_bullets").width()) / 2); }, 500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this simple thing os to define your function in particular window condition

like:

```
var width = $(window).width() //taking window width

if(width > 767){
//window width greater than 767
//your function here
        jQuery(window).on("swipeleft", function (event) {
            $(".DinM-navbar-toggle").click();


        });
        jQuery(window).on("swiperight", function (event) {
            $(".DinM-navbar-toggle").click();
        });

    }
```

what it will do it will fire your function in this condition on ly and when you will go in mobile and  refresh (refresh only in desktop ,in mobile it will take itself) your function won be disturbed..

with that you can also use bxslider or unslider with touch support in mobile as well